# Flutter - Build fail due to permission error when using google_maps_flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, maps

I have been using the google_maps_flutter plugin for a while now and after updating project and plugin versions to support AndroidX I am now getting a build failure when running `./gradlew build` from Android directory.

Flutter summary:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.2.2-pre.51, on Mac OS X 10.14.3)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.1.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.30.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Other info:

```
google_maps_flutter version: 0.2.0+3
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Error:

```
.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-0.2.0+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java:419: 
Error: Missing permissions required by GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled: 
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION 
or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION [MissingPermission]
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(myLocationEnabled);
```

I have declared the necessary permissions so I am not sure why that is failing.

---

Current workaround: I noticed that the manifest for the google_maps_flutter [plugin manifest](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) does not declare these permissions, so I copied a version locally, added the permissions and I am now able to build.

Does anyone know if it's expected that the manifest of the plugin also needs to declare the permissions? I dont know why this would be an issue now when it wasnt before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, these permissions were not added to the plugin's manifest so that only apps that use the feature will include the permission in their own app manifest.
You can see how this is done in the example app here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/0223a65a86c14f38de56c03f294235ad3536b1fb/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L5

We missed the part that Gradle is running this check and is failing the build if the permission is missing, I filed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28339 to fix that.